# Rails: joins with select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have two models:-
Customer and Account.
Customer has_one account and account belongs_to customer
I want to join the tables and fetch only some fields. My code:-

```
Customer.joins(:account).select("customers.id, customers.name, accounts.opening_balance")
```

It gives me Customer::ActiveRecord_Relation in result like this:-

```
 [#<Customer:0x00000005be0870 id: 1774, name: "James TEA">,
 #<Customer:0x00000005be0730 id: 1777, name: "Joseph STORE">,
 #<Customer:0x00000005be0578 id: 1835, name: "John CONFECTIONARY">,
 #<Customer:0x00000005be03e8 id: 1836, name: "Jerry PAN SHOP">]
```

No matter what I do, I am not able to get fields from right table(account in this case). Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
customers = Customer.joins(:account).select("customers.id, customers.name, accounts.opening_balance as opening_balance")
customers.first.opening_balance
```

Comment: sorry but I doubt it, you can check `Customer.joins(:account).select("customers.id, customers.name, accounts.opening_balance as opening_balance").explain`